# Query data from two tables and substitute foreign keys of first table with values of second

Tags: mysql, join

There is data table

```
mysql> select * from data;
+----+--------------------------------------+
| id | uid                                  |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | 466a5039-c4c1-403d-826d-07ed2399e288 |
|  2 | 188a193f-0638-4b71-9cda-03c30b4e008a |
|  3 | f8ed4eba-635b-4eff-a203-e72a8735fb27 |
|  4 | 7aa235f0-2441-4a00-bc5b-06194609a3d0 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and relation table

```
mysql> select * from relation;
+----+---------+----------+
| id | left    | right    |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |        3 |
|  2 |       4 |        2 |
+----+---------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`left` and `right` are foreign keys and both reference `data(id)`

I need to build query which would return this result

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| left_uid                             | right_uid                            |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 466a5039-c4c1-403d-826d-07ed2399e288 | f8ed4eba-635b-4eff-a203-e72a8735fb27 |
| 7aa235f0-2441-4a00-bc5b-06194609a3d0 | 188a193f-0638-4b71-9cda-03c30b4e008a |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is a simple join statement.  Please show what you've tried so far and detail what errors you see, if any.

Comment: Well, may be you are right and this is really simple join statement. I'm sorry in case this site is just for "difficult" questions to SQL masters. I used to use inner/outer left/right joins (which I thought were simple joins) but I didn't know how to apply that knowledge to current case and thus I didn't have tries. Now I have SQL query optimization questions but I'm not sure I can ask them here. Where I can learn what questions I can ask on this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(B.uid,'') left_uid,
    IFNULL(C.uid,'') right_uid
FROM
    relation A
    LEFT JOIN data B ON A.left  = B.id
    LEFT JOIN data C ON A.right = C.id
;
```

I did it as `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` in case data is missing from `data` table

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA

```
drop database if exists gumkins;
create database gumkins;
use gumkins
create table data
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    uid char(36),
    primary key (id)
);
create table relation
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    `left` int not null,
    `right` int not null,
    primary key (id)
);
insert into data (uid) values ('466a5039-c4c1-403d-826d-07ed2399e288');
insert into data (uid) values ('188a193f-0638-4b71-9cda-03c30b4e008a');
insert into data (uid) values ('f8ed4eba-635b-4eff-a203-e72a8735fb27');
insert into data (uid) values ('7aa235f0-2441-4a00-bc5b-06194609a3d0');
insert into relation (`left`,`right`) values (1,3);
insert into relation (`left`,`right`) values (4,2);
```

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA EXECUTED

```
mysql> drop database if exists gumkins;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> create database gumkins;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use gumkins
Database changed
mysql> create table data
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     uid char(36),
    ->     primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> create table relation
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     `left` int not null,
    ->     `right` int not null,
    ->     primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into data (uid) values ('466a5039-c4c1-403d-826d-07ed2399e288');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into data (uid) values ('188a193f-0638-4b71-9cda-03c30b4e008a');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into data (uid) values ('f8ed4eba-635b-4eff-a203-e72a8735fb27');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into data (uid) values ('7aa235f0-2441-4a00-bc5b-06194609a3d0');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into relation (`left`,`right`) values (1,3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into relation (`left`,`right`) values (4,2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA LOADED

```
mysql> select * from data;
+----+--------------------------------------+
| id | uid                                  |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | 466a5039-c4c1-403d-826d-07ed2399e288 |
|  2 | 188a193f-0638-4b71-9cda-03c30b4e008a |
|  3 | f8ed4eba-635b-4eff-a203-e72a8735fb27 |
|  4 | 7aa235f0-2441-4a00-bc5b-06194609a3d0 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from relation;
+----+------+-------+
| id | left | right |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 |    1 |     3 |
|  2 |    4 |     2 |
+----+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     IFNULL(B.uid,'') left_uid,
    ->     IFNULL(C.uid,'') right_uid
    -> FROM
    ->     relation A
    ->     LEFT JOIN data B ON A.left  = B.id
    ->     LEFT JOIN data C ON A.right = C.id
    -> ;
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| left_uid                             | right_uid                            |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 466a5039-c4c1-403d-826d-07ed2399e288 | f8ed4eba-635b-4eff-a203-e72a8735fb27 |
| 7aa235f0-2441-4a00-bc5b-06194609a3d0 | 188a193f-0638-4b71-9cda-03c30b4e008a |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!